# How to reinstall yum and what does 'rpm = 4.8.0-55.el6' mean?

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

There is an error with command `yum`. I believe it's a difficult problem searching several days without a solution way. I finally decide to reinstall python and yum. I have yet installed python successfully, but unfortunately, failed to install yum.

First, I deleted python and yum from the system based on CentOS6.5

```
# rpm -qa|grep python|xargs rpm -ev --allmatches --nodeps 
# whereis python |xargs rm -frv
# whereis python 
# rpm -qa|grep yum|xargs rpm -ev --allmatches --nodeps
# whereis yum |xargs rm -frv
```

Then, I downloaded those files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   77968 Aug 19  2016 python-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  176932 Aug 19  2016 python-devel-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   37052 Jul  3  2011 python-iniparse-0.3.1-2.1.el6.noarch.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5589812 Aug 19  2016 python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   78448 May 12  2016 python-pycurl-7.19.0-9.el6.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  343724 Jul  3  2011 python-setuptools-0.6.10-3.el6.noarch.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   87660 May 12  2016 python-urlgrabber-3.9.1-11.el6.noarch.rpm
# System need rpm-python 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   61520 May 12  2016 rpm-python-4.8.0-55.el6.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1042364 Mar 23 23:04 yum-3.2.29-81.el6.centos.noarch.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   27224 Sep 26  2011 yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-16.el6.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   30484 Mar 23 22:59 yum-plugin-aliases-1.1.30-40.el6.noarch.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   33524 Mar 23 23:00 yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-40.el6.noarch.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   26284 Mar 23 22:59 yum-plugin-protectbase-1.1.30-40.el6.noarch.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  115416 Mar 23 23:00 yum-utils-1.1.30-40.el6.noarch.rpm
```

I ran `rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs python*.rpm` to successfully reinstall python.

```
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:python-libs            ########################################### [ 14%]
   2:python                 ########################################### [ 29%]
   3:python-pycurl          ########################################### [ 43%]
   4:python-urlgrabber      ########################################### [ 57%]
   5:python-devel           ########################################### [ 71%]
   6:python-iniparse        ########################################### [ 86%]
   7:python-setuptools      ########################################### [100%]
```

In the final step, I ran `rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs rpm-python*.rpm yum*.rpm` but it failed. Below is the error message:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    rpm = 4.8.0-55.el6 is needed by rpm-python-4.8.0-55.el6.x86_64
    libxml2-python is needed by yum-utils-1.1.30-40.el6.noarch

# rpm --version
RPM version 4.8.0
```

I can't find anything about `rpm = 4.8.0-55.el6`, what the hell it is? Hope for your helping, thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you download the packages from?

Comment: @fpmurphy1   http://mirrors.163.com/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the `rpm-python` package is looking for a very specific version of `rpm`, i.e. `rpm-4.8.0-55.el6`

Comment: So how to solve it? I have downloaded `rpm-4.8.0-55.el6.x86_64.rpm` and tried to run `rpm -Uvh rpm-4.8.0-55.el6.x86_64.rpm` but there are some errors:
`error: Failed dependencies:
 rpm = 4.8.0-27.el6 is needed by (installed) rpm-libs-4.8.0-27.el6.x86_64
 rpm = 4.8.0-37.el6 is needed by (installed) rpm-libs-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64`